# Cannot read property 'context' of undefined

Tags: experience-editor, upgrade

After migration from **Sitecore 8.2 Update-5** to **Sitecore 9 Update-1** I see JavaScript error in Experience Editor mode.

For example:

I have a content page. Under content page I'm storing datasource items. Content page has some components which are using these datasource items. After changing datasource data in Experience Editor and clicking Save button I see error in browser console (Chrome, IE, FF):

```
> 16349168387717799575.JS:957 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined
>     at Object.showPublishAffectedPagesNotification (16349168387717799575.JS:957)
>     at 16349168387717799575.JS:939
>     at ExperienceEditor.js:142
>     at Object.onRequestProcessorSuccessCallback (ExperienceEditor.js:1015)
>     at Object.success (ExperienceEditor.js:990)
>     at fire (jquery-2.1.1.js:3073)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.js:3185)
>     at done (jquery-2.1.1.js:8251)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.1.js:8598)
>     at Object.send (jquery-2.1.1.js:8623)
```

Please, help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you compare ExperienceEditor.js with same file from a clean solution

Comment: I’ve just compared files. They are the same. No any difference.

Comment: Something is different after your upgrade, file wise. Can you use Beyond Compare and compare your bin folder and /Sitecore folder to a clean install. See if you can see any major differences.

Comment: Just wondering if you resolved this @AndreiPaliakou - have seen the same come up on our Sitecore 9 Update 1 installation.  We've been running this for a while though and not seen before.  Seems to come up for us though when the page loads in the Experience Editor.

Comment: Also having this issue, Sitecore 9.

Comment: @AndyButland I was able to resolve this issue. Check my answer.

Comment: @chilly I was able to resolve this issue. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue.

You will need to change `sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\Commands\ShowDataSources.js`.

Search for line:

```
this.command.context.app.showNotification("notification", notificationTitle, true);
```

and replace it with:

```
this.commandContext.app.showNotification("notification", notificationTitle, true);
```

After this fix console error will not appear and you should able to see Experience Editor notification:

[image]

**Update:**

In Sitecore 9.3 it was fixed like:

```
showPublishAffectedPagesNotification: function (context) {
      var notificationTitle = TranslationUtil.translateTextByServer(TranslationUtil.keys.This_component_contains_associated_content_If_you_publish_this_component_the_associated_content_is_also_published_to_a_number_of_other_pages_that_use_the_same_associated_content, ExperienceEditor);
      // notificationTitle = notificationTitle.replace("{0}", result.inFinalStateCountAndNotPublished);
      var currentContext = context.context || context;
      currentContext.app.showNotification("notification", notificationTitle, true);
    },
```